# C++: Case insensitive "Boost:unordered_map" does not work?

Tags: c++, boost, case-insensitive, unordered-map

I tried to switch from std::unordered_map (VS2010) to boost::unordered_map (version 1.48) and surprisingly, some important test cases failed in my project. I tracked down the cause and come to the conclusion that boost::unordered_map does not honor my case insensitive equality provider:

```
struct StringEqualityCaseInsensitive : public std::equal_to<String>
{
    bool operator ()(const String& a, const String& b) const { return boost::iequals<String, String>(a, b); }
};

boost::unordered_map<string, int, boost::hash<string>, StringEqualityCaseInsensitive> map;
```

Now I just add some uppercase elements and search for their lowercase counterparts (using the find() member method). If I use the std::unordered_map it works just fine and with boost it doesn't. The cruel thing is that if I look for uppercase elements, the equality comparator gets invoked and when I look for lowercase, it doesn't get invoked...

Anyone's got a clue, why is this? (Not sure if this is important but I am using the Intel Compiler 12.1 with C++0x support enabled)

EDIT: Damn, now it dawns on me. Maybe I need to also adjust the hash class to return the same value independently of lower/upper-case. But still its strange that they have different behaviour?!

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because case differences produce different hashes, which is bit more important for a hash map than equality test.

Comment: Then there is the immediate question, how do I make the hash function case insensitive ^^?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt it will work in either `boost::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_map`, because your hash function is defined wrongly. The default `boost::hash<string>` is *not* case insensitive, meaning one of the fundamental assumption of hash tables

```
a == b   =>   hash(a) == hash(b)
```

is broken (i.e. `HELLO` and `hello` could generate different hashes). The two maps give different result is just an implementation detail.

Comment: I agree with you ;). Surprisingly, as I mentioned, it still works with std. At least for my test cases, but I was not validating the container, the container is just used in the test case so this could be a coincidence. Also now when I think about it, it really can't be that this works without a proper hash function ;). Stupid!

Comment: @thesaint: Could you give some test cases?

Comment: BTW, is there not something like "boost::test_container(my_map)" so that the template instance gets validated against specifications?!

Comment: "Could you give some test cases?"   Well, it's probably not worth it since the count of elements is just too low and also ordered in some sense. This really can be a coincidence.

Comment: Ok now it seems to work fine ;). Still thanks, even if this was rather obvious. I am just not used to C++ that much!